# Next.js apps don't work on volume license Word add in/IE11

Tags: next.js, ms-word

Next.js apps doesn't work on volume license version of Microsoft Word.

IE11 is built-in, and when I run my Next.js app on it, it gets the following error.

```
Error: 未定義のエラーです。(Undefined error.)
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "未定義のエラーです。(Undefined error.)",
      message: "未定義のエラーです。(Undefined error.)",
      name: "Error",
      number: -2147467259,
      stack: "Error: 未定義のエラーです。(Undefined error.)
   at value (https://**********/_next/static/chunks/main-ea5363f7b1817a1ef87a.js:1:51576)
   at e (https://**********/_next/static/chunks/main-ea5363f7b1817a1ef87a.js:1:46612)
   at a (https://**********/_next/static/chunks/main-ea5363f7b1817a1ef87a.js:1:1502)
   at a (https://**********/_next/static/chunks/main-ea5363f7b1817a1ef87a.js:1:1347)
   at t.createRouter (https://**********/_next/static/chunks/main-ea5363f7b1817a1ef87a.js:1:29243)
   at Anonymous function (https://**********/_next/static/chunks/main-ea5363f7b1817a1ef87a.js:1:14052)
   at l (https://**********/_next/static/chunks/main-ea5363f7b1817a1ef87a.js:1:71920)
   at Anonymous function (https://**********/_next/static/chunks/main-ea5363f7b1817a1ef87a.js:1:71729)
   at Anonymous function (https://**********/_next/static/chunks/main-ea5363f7b1817a1ef87a.js:1:72364)
   at k (https://**********/_next/static/chunks/main-ea5363f7b1817a1ef87a.js",
      Symbol()_g.k4lzz4di5i0: undefined,
      Symbol(ASSET_LOAD_ERROR)_15.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(mui.nested)_1d.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)_18.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.async_mode)_19.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.block)_z.k4lzz4di551: undefined,
      Symbol(react.concurrent_mode)_1a.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.context)_t.k4lzz4di5i0: undefined,
      Symbol(react.debug_trace_mode)_12.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.element)_n.k4lzz4di5i0: undefined,
      Symbol(react.forward_ref)_u.k4lzz4di5i0: undefined,
      Symbol(react.fragment)_p.k4lzz4di5i0: undefined,
      Symbol(react.fundamental)_1b.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.lazy)_x.k4lzz4di551: undefined,
      Symbol(react.legacy_hidden)_14.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.memo)_w.k4lzz4di551: undefined,
      Symbol(react.offscreen)_13.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.opaque.id)_11.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.portal)_o.k4lzz4di5i0: undefined,
      Symbol(react.profiler)_r.k4lzz4di5i0: undefined,
      Symbol(react.provider)_s.k4lzz4di5i0: undefined,
      Symbol(react.responder)_1c.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.scope)_10.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.server.block)_1e.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(react.strict_mode)_q.k4lzz4di5i0: undefined,
      Symbol(react.suspense)_v.k4lzz4di5i0: undefined,
      Symbol(react.suspense_list)_y.k4lzz4di551: undefined,
      Symbol(SSG_DATA_NOT_FOUND)_16.k4lzz4di55: undefined,
      Symbol(x)_17.k4lzz4di55: undefined
   }
```

Even a most minimal Next.js app doesn't work on the Word.

```bash
npx create-next-app@latest # app name: test
cd test
npm run build
npm run start
```

It gives the same undefined error. But the both apps work on the IE11 browser.

What should I do with my Next.js apps to run on volume license Microsoft Word.

Word version:
Word 2019 Version 1808 (Build: 10389.20033)

Comment: hi thanks for reaching out and sorry to hear that this is now not working, but from the logs I am afraid there isn't much information I can get especially with some Japanese error messages. Generally, Add-in should support the Next.js react framework. Would you please follow these docs to see whether there are something missed? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8zIHNtMSmE

Comment: Hi, the Japanese message is "未定義のエラーです。", which means "Undefined error.". That's the only Japanese message we see in the log, and I don't think it's a problem. I checked the docs but those are for React. I'm already using the Next.js and since the project is growing bigger, I don't want to replace it with React.

Comment: Next.js is also a react framework, right? I am afraid in order to import it to add-in, some configurations need to be done and the existing add-in template with react support is a good reference for which configurations need to be added.

Also it's always a good idea to start from a new small add-in template and add Next.js support from there. After it's working, then try to import your whole project.